# Lower-case URLs - is a good practice?

Tags: asp.net, url, routes

In ASP.NET web application **is it a good practice to keep lower-case URLs?** Default routes are in **CamelCase manner**, like `/Home/Index, /Account/Login`.

But it cuts my eyes.. Is it a good practice to lower-case routes to make like this - `/home/index` and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is a good practice to use lower-case in urls.
I can't even remember any popular site using CamelCase in addresses.